# ¿Como refactorizar para utilizar promises y ordenar mi codigo correctamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Esto es lo que debo hacer

1. ver si existe el filtro en la url, si existe cambiar el flujo
2. El filtro de categorias es asincronico asi que debo refactorizar el "loadCategoriesFilter" para usar promises.

Esto es lo que tengo, por separado:

```
if (!emptyProducts) {
        loadCategoriesFilter();
        loadStockFilter();

        if (existsCategoryFilter) { 
        }
        applyFilter();

    }
```

Luego, para ver si existe el filtro en la url, si existe cambiar el flujo:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); 
    var categoryId =  urlParams.get("categoryId")
    $.post(url + '?categoryId=' + categoryId, function(response){

    })
```

- Filtro por categorías

  ```
  var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
  var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

  $.post(url, function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
          categories = [];

          $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
              categories.push(element);
          });

          getParentCategories(categories);
      }
  }, 'json');
  ```

  };

y aqui mi refactor a chequear:

//Refactorizar el loadCategoriesFilter para usar promises

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.post(url,  resolve(response), 'json');

        });

        promise.then(
        function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                categories = [];

                $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
                    categories.push(element);
                });

                getParentCategories(categories);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar la función para que use promises, y admita categoryId como parámetro, partiendo de esta función:

```
var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

    $.post(url, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            categories = [];

            $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
                categories.push(element);
            });

            getParentCategories(categories);
        }
    }, 'json');
};
```

Haría una función algo así:

```
var loadCategoriesFilter = function(categoryId) {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';
    // aca el condicional
    if(categoryId){
        url = url + '?categoryId=' + categoryId;
    }
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.post(url, function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                categories = [];

                $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
                    categories.push(element);
                });
                // notar que getParentCategories no está más
                // se extrajo para manejarlo desde afuera y que esta función solo tenga una responsabilidad, checkear si es el caso    
                return resolve(categories);
            }
            else {
                // rechazar promise porque la respuesta no fue success
                return reject();
            }
        }, 'json')
            .fail(reject); // manejar posible error en la request rechazando la promise
    });

};
```

Que después se podría usar como:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); 
var categoryId =  urlParams.get("categoryId")
loadCategoriesFilter(categoryId)
    .then(getParentCategories)
    .then(function(withParentCategories){
        console.log(withParentCategories);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // hubo algún error, la promesa fue rechazada, manejar apropiadamente
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

si vas a migrar deveria ser del todo!

**javascript puro**

```
function loadCategoriesFilter (){
  fetch('https://example.com/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
        // en caso de querer enviar algo
       //body: JSON.stringify({a: 7, str: 'Some string: &=&'}) 
     }).then(
        res=>res.json()
      ).then( response =>{
          categories = [];

          for( x in response.categoryTree) {
              categories.push(response.categoryTree[x]);
          }

        getParentCategories(categories);

      }).catch(error=>
      console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message)
  );
}
```

**referencia:**
[fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)